# Why doesn't Craft think the Mcrypt extension is installed?

Tags: mcrypt

I am running the latest version of Homestead, and have installed Mcrypt, but I am getting an error that it is not installed while trying to update a site.

```
php7.0-mcrypt is already the newest version (7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
```

This is the php version I am running:

```
PHP 7.2.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2017 13:58:33) ( NTS )
```

I have rebooted the VM and still get the same result. Is there something else I am missing?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: PHP 7.2 dropped mcrypt from core.  If you need it, you have to install it separately via PECL: https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt  Sounds like you might just need to enable it in your php.ini now?

Comment: Thanks Brad. That's what I was reading as well. I wasn't seeing it in my php.ini. 
I just ended up rolling back my homestead version. Just the easiest in my case ¯\_(ツ)_/¯